# How can I Select the data from the database using Comma

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image][image: Need Stock Table]

This is my Need Stock Table. Here I want to select Id, Name based on the NeedGroupIds. This is fine but here the problem is, If I am passing just `12,15` then it gives the output. But if I am passing simply `12` means I need to get the output as two rows that is `Markers` and `intel` but failing.

How can I select the data based on comma.

Comment: try to copy paste,why put as image or post in sqlfiddle  and format the question with what is required correctly!!

Answer (score 0):

***MySQL***:  Use [**FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM my_table
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(value_to_find, NeedGroupIds);  
/** if found, find_in_set should result in a number > zero **/
```

**Example 1**:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( 6, ',5,6,7,' ); -- results 3  
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( '7', ',5,6,7,' ); -- results 4  
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( '8', ',5,6,7,' ); -- results 0
```

---

***MsSQL***: Use [**LIKE (Transact-SQL)**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
/** For non-mysql databases, an alternate to FIND_IN_SET **/  
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM my_table
  WHERE ',' + NeedGroupIds + ',' LIKE '%,12,%';
```

**Example 2**:

```
/** this should result `Markers` **/  
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM my_table  
  WHERE ',' + NeedGroupIds + ',' LIKE '%,12,15,%';  

/** this should result `Markers` and `intel` **/  
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM my_table  
  WHERE ',' + NeedGroupIds + ',' LIKE '%,12,%';  

/** this should result `Pen` and `cello` **/  
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM my_table  
  WHERE ',' + NeedGroupIds + ',' LIKE '%,2,%';
```

---

***Refer to***: [**Alternate to FIND_IN_SET for non-MySQL databases**](http://blogs.digitss.com/database/alternate-to-find_in_set-for-non-mysql-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE  fieldName REGEXP '^9,|,9$|,9,' OR fieldName =9
```

For more information you can see documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html